# Tabs don't work on ng2-ace-editor in html mode for Angular 9

Tags: angular, tabs, ace-editor

I'm using ng2-ace-editor in an Angular 9 project to implement a litle editor but I find this problem:
Indent tabs not works in 'html' mode but works perfect in javascript mode. I try to add emmet or update Brace, but not works.

I saw that it works until when I try to import the emmet or the snippets assets.

Can someone help me to put emmet and snippets?

in html:

```
<div ace-editor [(text)]="variableText" [mode]="'html'" [options]="options" [theme]="'monokai'"></div>
```

At the top of the component:

```
import 'brace';
import 'brace/mode/html';
import 'brace/mode/scss';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/snippets/javascript';
import 'brace/snippets/scss';
import 'brace/snippets/html';
import 'brace/ext/emmet';
```

options in component:

```
  options: any = {
    useSoftTabs: true,
    tabSize: 4,
    printMargin: false,
    enableEmmet: true
  };
```

Comment: try calling setOptions of the editor instance, maybe angular wrapper doesn't pass it correctly

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work.
if I import 'brace/ext/emmet' the tab is blocked automatically for the html i scss mode. even though I use the setOptions

Comment: unfortunately this is a bug in old version of ace which is used by brace